# How to check a string for elements in an array in python 3.4

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-3.4

Lets say I have the following variables...

```
bad_words = ['bad0', 'bad1', 'bad2']
bad_string = "This string has bad1 in it."
bad_string2 = "This string is abcbad0xyz."
good_string = "This string is good!"
```

What's the best way to look through the strings for the 'bad words' and only print out the good string?

Example...

```
def check_words(string):
    bad_words = ['bad0', 'bad1', 'bad2']
    #this is where I need help... 
    #Return False if string contains any of the words in bad words
    #Return True if string does not contain bad words.


bad_string = "This string has bad1 in it."
good_string = "This string is good!"

#call the check_words method by sending one of the strings
valid = check_words(bad_string)    #I want this to return False

if valid:
    print("Good string!")
else:
    print("Bad string!")

#or...
valid = check_words(good_string)    #I want this to return True

if valid:
    print("Good string!")
else:
    print("Bad string!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward, iterate through the `bad_words` and check if word is in `string`, and return `False` if it is. After we check all the `bad_words` we can return `True` safely.

```
def check_words(string):
    bad_words = ['bad0', 'bad1', 'bad2']
    for word in bad_words:
        if word in string:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the builtin function `any()` to test if any "bad words" are in your strings:

```
def check_words(string, words):
  return any(word in string for word in words)
```

`string` would be you string for testing, and `words` would be your list of bad words. This works by testing if any word from the `words` list is in your string. The `any()` function then returns a boolean based upon your conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions to match any of the bad words:

```
is_bad = re.search('|'.join(bad_words), bad_string) != None
```

`bad_string` is the string to test, `is_bad` is `True` or `False`, depending on whether `bad_string` has bad words or not.